# How to use result of function as an argument of the same function multiple times?

Tags: python

I have a simple algorithm which calculate GCD for 2 integers.
What I'm trying to do is to use result of this function to calculate GCD for more then 2 integers. For example GCD for 99 and 22 is 11. Then I want to use 11 as first integer and some number. The thing is I don't know how to use a first result to calculate another one. Especially if there are more then 3 integers because user decides for how many of them the GCD will be calculated.
Here is my code (which work only for 2 integers):

```
required_inputs = int(input("For how many numbers would you like to find their GCD?: "))
received_inputs = []

for num in range(0, required_inputs):
    values = int(input())
    received_inputs.append(values)
if len(received_inputs) == 0:
    values = int(input())
    received_inputs.append(values)

def GCD(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return GCD(b, a % b)

print(GCD(received_inputs[0], received_inputs[1]))
```

Comment: `Recursion`, you mean?

Comment: Recursion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910900/how-to-use-result-of-function-as-an-argument-of-the-same-function-multiple-times#comment88822019_50910900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea is to use recursion for combining the results as well as in the algorithm itself then this will work:

```
def GCD(*numbers):
    a, b = numbers[:2]
    if len(numbers) == 2:
        if b == 0:
            return a
        else:
            return GCD(b, a % b)
    else:
        return GCD(GCD(a, b), *numbers[2:])


print(GCD(*received_inputs))
```

Another options include a loop (ok) or using `functools.reduce` (not recommended as not readable enough).

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are talking about recursion:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

Basically you just do another call to the same method, inside of that method:

```
def calc_factorial(x):
    """This is a recursive function
    to find the factorial of an integer"""

    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * calc_factorial(x - 1)

num = 4
print("The factorial of {} is {}".format(num, calc_factorial(num)))
```

Comment: But how to implement this in my code, I understand the concept of recursion. However I don't know how to use it in my case, it seem it is written for max 3 iterations. Here theoretically can be infinite numbers of operations because it depends on user input.